# Changes in js file not getting reflected in frontend in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, javascript

I did some changes in js file of a third party extension. The path shown on frontend is

> /pub/static/version1574138983/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer.min.js

I did changes in

> app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/view/layer.js

This is the only file i think is responsible.
Any changes done in this file is not getting reflected on frontend.
I had run `static-content deploy` command also,but still did not work.

Comment: have you checked pub/static folder? Is there available whatever changes you made?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your file **layer.js**

I will Explain why this Happen because you have enable the minify of JS.

Once you have enable the Minify JS. your JS file create min file then this name converts in **.min.js** & minify file creates in pub/static Path then now:

```
Your file path: app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/view/layer.js

saved by Magento Path: /pub/static/version1574138983/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation/js/view/layer.min.js
```

Command to Execute after Changes are:

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f && chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Hope you understand!!

Answer (score 1):

Try following way...

> 1. Enable developer mode: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.
> 2. First change in js `app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/web/js/view/layer.js`
> 3. Clean `pub/static/frontend` directory.
> 4. Run `php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy -f`
> 5. Clean cache and also browser cache .